# Does the class of all periodic subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ of peroid greater than $k$ form a field of sets?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

We say that a subset $X\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is a periodic subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ of period $k$ if the set obtained from $X$ by adding $k$ to each element of $X$ is  $X$ itself.

Does the class of all  periodic subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ of peroid greater than $k$  form a field of sets?

Here is a sketch of what I think: If $A_m,A_n$ are two periodic sets of  periods  $m,n$ respectively then their union is a periodic set of period $m\times n $. And $A_m'$ is a periodic set of period  $m$.

Did I miss something?